# Replacing rgb from multiple lines with a one line version

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to convert:

```
<r>240</r>
<g>240</g>
<b>240</b>
```

to:

```
rgb="240,240,240"
```

using Notepad++. I've tried

```
<r>(\d+)</r>$<g>(\d+)</g>$<b>(\d+)</b>
```

but it didn't work. I have about 20+ files containing multiple occurrences of this and would appreciate any help I can get. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ won't do a multiline regex. You first have to replace all of the newlines in the file. You can then do a regex replace with

```
regex: <r>(\d+)</r><g>(\d+)</g><b>(\d+)</b>
replace: rgb="\1,\2,\3"\r\n
```

Or you can break it up into more steps and do each line individually.

```
regex: <r>(\d+)</r>
replace: rgb="\1,
```

then

```
regex: <g>(\d+)</g>
replace: \1,
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my system, I highlighted the tags then did `search->Replace` make sure you have checked `Match Whole Word Only` and `Wrap around`. worked for me replacing the text in multiple files.